# How to embed WPF Window into another Window and adjust its size via XAML or code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

First of all it's my first day using Xaml so this question might be dummy for you, but i totally got lost.

## Overview

My technique is that i have MainWindow.xaml and it's split into three areas (using grid columns) the columns width being set automatically.

Based on some actions in the right column, the middle column with show a page let's say Page.xaml that exists in different namespace.

## What i'm seeking for

The problem is i need to set the width and height for this page to be equal the middle column width and height as it will fit this area.

## Notes

I have very small experience with xaml and binding techniques.

> MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" 
    WindowState="Maximized"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="MainWindow" d:DesignWidth="1366" d:DesignHeight="768">

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*" x:Name="LeftColoumn" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" x:Name="CenterColoumn" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*" x:Name="RightColoumn" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="RightStackPanel" Background="LightGray" >
            <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="50" >
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontStyle="Normal" Margin="3" FontSize="20" >Others</TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <Expander x:Name="Expander1" Header="Others" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Button  Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=RightStackPanel}" Background="White" Content="Add" Height="50" Click="Button_Click" ></Button>
            </Expander>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Frame  Grid.Column="0" x:Name="LeftFrame" Background="LightGray"  ></Frame>
    <Frame  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="CenterFrame" Background="DarkGray" ></Frame>

</Grid></Window>
```

> Other Xaml file

```
<Page
  x:Name="Page"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="Any" d:DesignWidth="1364" d:DesignHeight="868"
  >

<Grid>
    <Frame   Background="DarkGray" />

</Grid></Page>
```

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame middleFrame=CenterColumn;
        Otherxaml other=new Otherxaml();
        middleFrame.Source = new Uri("OtherxamlPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }
```

Comment: Please include your XAML proto with at least hardcoded width/height and screenshot of the desired result. It seems that you can just set wpf "stretch" property of the controls to solve your problem. Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell thanks for your reply , the other xaml file is yet empty because i can't start implementing it before i determine it's width and height. Thanks again

Comment: It's very unclear what are you trying to achieve. "The other XAML" - is it a standard WPF control (like for e.g. TextBlock), or Custom Control? Please clarify. In general, you can place that "other XAML" control into Grid cell and stretch it to the size of that cell automatically, as I've told you before. Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell Thanks for your reply again. The other xaml files as you can see is a simple page i load it into the grid column at runtime. I hope my point is now clear, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pertinent to your code snippet, you may place the `OtherxamlPage.xaml` inside the central frame and set the properties of that frame like shown below:

```
<Frame  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="CenterFrame" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Source="OtherxamlPage.xaml" Background="DarkGray" />
```

You can set the Source="`OtherxamlPage.xaml`" dynamically in event handler, e.g. `Button.Click` as per your example.

Alternatively, consider the creation of WPF `UserControl`  (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294992.aspx) instead of that other XAML Window (or Page) and place it directly into the grid cell. In both cases set the content "Stretch" property in order to adjust its size automatically, thus you won't need to specify it in the code.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. with little changes in my code it finally worked but i faced another problem that is i need to know the width and height values to set the design width and height property to start working on them. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. At this point I would consider this issue resolved, thus closing this comments thread. Should you have other questions, please post them separately. Good luck with your project. Best regards,